# is it possible to install latest azure-cli in ubuntu arm64

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to find some solution to install latest az-cli for ubuntu arm64 but sadly i'm not able to?

can someone suggest me how can i use az-cli on ubuntu arm?

note:
i'm able to install older version but not working as expected. that's why looking for a newer or latest version

```
saan@sg-vm1:~$ az --version
azure-cli                         2.0.81

core                              2.0.81
telemetry                          1.0.4

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.17.0

Python location '/usr/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/saan/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like no https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt#overview

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but you could try to add a bash task with `az upgrade --yes`

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would install azure CLI on Ubuntu with this command:

```
sudo curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

This installs package dependencies, adds the Microsoft Azure package repository and installs the **azure-cli**. The problem is the **azure-cli** package in that repo for arm64 is broken, the included python3.10 executable is for x86_64 architecture.

Therefore, until the **azure-cli** is fixed (the problem can be tracked with this issue, starting at the comment https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7368#issuecomment-753511197) use python pip to install the Azure cli.

To install just for your user account.

```
pip3 install --user azure-cli
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.40.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.40.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.8",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

To install globally (needs root access):

```
sudo pip3 install azure-cli
az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.40.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.40.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.8",
  "extensions": {}
}
```